# SageMaker ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTrainingJob operation: Could not assume role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

When I get to Notebook Instance in SageMaker and create model in **linear_learner_mnist** example I get error even when I have the role with **AmazonSageMakerFullAccess**and **AssumeRole** attached policies attached.
When I add  **AdministratorAccess**policy to the role - all works fine. What am I missing here?

role exists and attached

```
Resources:
  SageMakerExecutionRole:
    Condition: RoleArnEmpty
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "sagemaker.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSageMakerFullAccess"
      Path: "/service-role/"
      Policies:
        Fn::If:
        - S3BucketNotEmpty
        -
          - PolicyName: SageMakerS3BucketAccess
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: '2012-10-17'
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - s3:*
                  Resource:
                    - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${SageMakerS3Bucket}'
                    - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${SageMakerS3Bucket}/*'
        - Ref: AWS::NoValue
```

> ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the
> CreateTrainingJob operation: Could not assume role
> arn:aws:iam::XXX:role/sagemaker-stack-SageMakerExecutionRole-1JT7AT4OPUK9R.
> Please ensure that the role exists and allows principal
> 'sagemaker.amazonaws.com' to assume the role.

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised that everything works normally when you add the AdministratorAccess policy.  The error and how to correct it is documented at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-roles.html.

> An Amazon SageMaker user can grant these permissions with an IAM role (referred to as an execution role). The user passes the role when making these API calls: CreateNotebookInstance, CreateHyperParameterTuningJob, CreateTrainingJob, and CreateModel.
>
> You attach the following trust policy to the IAM role which grants Amazon SageMaker principal permissions to assume the role, and is the same for all of the execution roles:
>
> ```
> {
>     "Version": "2012-10-17",
>     "Statement": [
>         {
>             "Effect": "Allow",
>             "Principal": {
>                 "Service": "sagemaker.amazonaws.com"
>             },
>             "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

In the Identity and Access Management (IAM) Console, I added the statement section above to the trust policy under the trust relationships section of my role, and it fixed this error for me.

Comment: This still doesn't work at times.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create an IAM role based on the CloudFormation template you provided and got a role with ARN - arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/service-role/test-iam-SageMakerExecutionRole-187YIQM7UMMXF.

I think the issue is the role ARN you set when creating the training job is not correct. You probably need to add "/service-role" before the role name.